# Databind to dynamically created objects knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I have some html elements that i create using a foreach loop in a cshtml view like so.

```
 @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.DataFromCsv.Columns)
               {
                 <option>@col.ColumnName</option>
                }
```

How would i go about creating an observable array or binding to an observable array to get the value of these properties?

So if my model is

```
public class Model

    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

and in my viewmodel i have

```
 self.ModelObservable = {
    FirstName: ko.observable(),
    LastName: ko.observable(),
    Id: ko.observable()
}
```

How would i bind to those created objects?

Should it be

```
<option data-bind=value: ModelObservable.item?>
```

Comment: For `<select>` you can find information in this link:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html.  You don't bind to an `<option>` element but to a `<select>` one.

Comment: Are you asking how to bind things? That's a pretty generic question; you might want to start with some of the tutorials on the knockout website. http://learn.knockoutjs.com/

Comment: My question (perhaps i should rephrase) is how to bind to the dynamically created html elements. I.e. foreach <option data-bind="value: ModelObservable.item?">

Comment: so I believe your options are going to be serializing your mvc model or viewbag  into JSON in some fashion (newtonsoft is great for that) and then abandoning the razor syntax and let knockout handle that or  use the knockout mvc add in. here is an example for a collection.    http://knockoutmvc.com/Collections